# Display name of driver who have never been assigned a shift

Tags: sql, oracle

I am supposed to display drivers who have not been assigned a shift. I have joined the table through the primary key of the driver number. Here's my code.

```
select distinct dr_drvname
from driver,shift
where dr_drvnum <> sh_drvnum;
```

I have made the driver numbers not equal in my code to show the ones not qualified but this code displays all the drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In counterpoint to Justin's answer, here's a version using joins:

```
SELECT d.dr_drvname
FROM driver d
LEFT JOIN shift s
          ON s.sh_drvnum = d.dr_drvnum
WHERE s.sh_drvnum IS NULL
```

In general, it's preferable to always explicitly specify your joins, not to use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause).

(but *why* are you prefixing columns with a -short- table prefix: `'dr_'`?  Including in the initial table?  When you appear to have them prefixed with a slightly longer one anyways: `'drv'`?)

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll be specifying it from now on. The naming is due to tables given to me, I did not create it myself

Answer (score 3):

Guessing at your table structure, I suspect you want something like

```
select d.dr_drvname
  from driver d
 where not exists( select 1
                     from shift s
                    where d.dr_drvnum = s.sh_drvnum );
```

Comment: thanks this works, but i have a question. What is the purpose of "select 1" and from shift "s". what is the significance of the s?

Comment: @JohnnyNguyen - `s` and `d` are simply aliases for the two tables.  It's generally a good idea to use aliases so that you are explicitly specifying which table a particular column is coming from.  The `NOT EXISTS` clause is simply concerned with whether the inner query returns a row not the values that are returned so what you select is immaterial.  I could select a column from either table or some arbitrary string constant without changing the meaning of the query.